# When should I use "didn't" instead of "haven't"?

Tags: tense, difference, verb-forms, perfect-constructions

Is *haven't* supposed to mean something I may still do and *didn't* not?

Can I use *didn't* for something I might still do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Haven't* and *didn't* are different time-wise, as you have guessed correctly. *Haven't* refers to the past up until now. So if you *haven't* done something, you *haven't* done it for a specific period of time (day, month, ever, etc.)

*Didn't* refers to a specific point of time that has already passed. For example, if it is 7 PM, you could say "I *didn't* eat dinner at 6" or "I *haven't* eaten dinner yet today". In both instances, you can still eat dinner. Plus, it is possible for you to have eaten dinner at a different time if you use *didn't*, but not with *haven't*, since you specified today.

Answer (score 1):

When answering a question, take your cue from the form used in the question and answer accordingly. For example, "*Have you been out today?*" expects an answer like "*No, I haven't (yet)*" as opposed to "No I didn't", which would sound wrong.

"*Did you write that letter?*" expects a response such as "*Yes, I did*", and not "*Yes, I have*."