# "I didn't have a laptop before" vs. "I haven't had a laptop before" in context

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Could you tell me if there is any difference between the past simple and the present perfect in the following context.

> I've just won a tablet. **I haven't had** a tablet before.
>
> I've just won a tablet. **I didn't have** a tablet before.

Comment: Does [this previous answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/385/when-should-i-use-didnt-instead-of-havent) help you?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but in this particular context it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They *could* apply to exactly the same circumstances; but they have different implications.

*I didn't have a tablet before* says that just before winning it, I didn't have one. I might have had one a while ago.

*I haven't had a tablet before* suggests that I have never had a tablet.  More precisely, it says that over some relevant period extending up to the present, I haven't had one. In the absence of any other information, that period will be taken to be from the beginning of time, i.e. *ever*.

Answer (score 1):

"I didn't have a tablet before." Means that before you won a tablet, you did not have one (at that time). I.E. In this case it is possible that you had owned one in the past, but did not at the time that you won one.

"I haven't had a tablet before." Means that you did not ever own a tablet before winning the tablet.